# Understanding the meaning of this compiler command

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, compiler-construction

I have been passed some flash work and have been given the below compiler command to use in the fsch.exe of the flex sdk to compile the swf.

**mxmlc  -allow-source-path-overlap=true -sp dependencies/  -sp dependencies/green-as3  -o test/frog.swf FrogMain.as -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true**

Can somebody explain what some of the elements of the command mean? It works, but I don't understand what their purpose is:

-allow-source-path-overlap=true
-sp (and why it is repeated twice)
-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true

Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html).

> Checks if a source-path entry is a subdirectory of another source-path
>   entry. It helps make the package names of MXML components unambiguous.
>
> This is an advanced option.

If I interpret these docs correctly, this helps solve "issues" when you have myComp.MXML and myComp.as in the same directory.

These lines:

> -sp dependencies/ -sp dependencies/green-as3

Are odd.  I suspect sp is setting the source path argument (a lot of arguments can be abbreviated, but that doesn't seem to be documented, or at least not well).  It looks to me like the second entry overwrites the first entry.  If you wanted to include both directories as source paths, you should do this:

> -sp dependencies/ -sp += dependencies/green-as3

I added a += on the second one.  It is possible the Flex Compiler does the "+=" automagically for source path; but that is not obvious from the docs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really appreciate it. I will look into the link to the docs that you have shared. Thanks again.